# Why don't materials and methods describe culture media in volume?

Tags: cell-culture, experimental-design, methods

After reading several materials and methods sections of cell culture experiments, I have not seen the recipe for culture media ever described in terms of volume.

> Human adipose tissue was obtained from six samples of abdominal fat from female donors (age range: 20–45 years) after receiving informed consent and cultured as described in a previous study.[15] Briefly, samples were washed extensively with sterile phosphate-buffered saline (PBS) to remove contaminating debris and red blood cells. Washed aspirates were treated with 0.075% collagenase type I in PBS for 30 min at 37°C with gentle agitation. The collagenase I was inactivated with an equal volume of DMEM: F12/10% fetal bovine serum (FBS) and the infranatant centrifuged for 10 min at 800 rpm. The cellular pellet was resuspended in DMEM: F12/10% FBS and plated at 20000 cells/cm2 in T75 flasks in DMEM: F12 medium supplemented with 10% FBS and %1 Penicillin/streptomycin. After 24 h, it removed the nonadherent cells and expanded the adherent ADAS cells by serial passage. In this study, we used cells at passages 3–5 for all experiments and all experiments repeated at least in triplicate.

In this excerpt from the paper, *Efficient transdifferentiation of human adipose-derived stem cells into Schwann-like cells: A promise for treatment of demyelinating diseases* by Razavi et al, there is no mention of the **volume** of media used to culture the cells.

Moreover, there is no description of the height of the media in the dish, so it seems to me that from most cell culture descriptions, there is no way to properly reproduce the experiment simply by reading the paper.

Why do these sections fail to specify volume information?
Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you checked reference 15?

Comment: @canadianer yes

Comment: The volume of media would be different for different culture vessels. You can check [this](https://www.thermofisher.com/ch/en/home/references/gibco-cell-culture-basics/cell-culture-protocols/cell-culture-useful-numbers.html) site for the usual volumes. If they have not indicated then probably they used the usual culture volumes. You can check out their supplementary methods for more details on different experiments.